# Unable to read table keys but getting keys values in real-time database in flutter

Tags: database, flutter, dart, real-time

In all of the code below is describes that how to fetch data from real-time database and get the data but not the parent key in with data is ?

[In this image I want to read Table keys and with other values but I get only values data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ2e3.jpg)

**This is a model class**

```
class Seller {
  final String address,
      businessType,
      description,
      fcm,
      name,
      onlineStatus,
      picUrl,
      uuid;
  final String blockByAdmin, completeOrders, rating;
  final String lat, lng;
  final String timeStamp;

  Seller(
      {this.address,
      this.blockByAdmin,
      this.businessType,
      this.description,
      this.completeOrders,
      this.fcm,
      this.timeStamp,
      this.lat,
      this.lng,
      this.name,
      this.onlineStatus,
      this.picUrl,
      this.rating,
      this.uuid});

  factory Seller.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot) {
    return Seller(
      address: snapshot["address"],
      blockByAdmin: snapshot["blockByAdmin"],
      businessType: snapshot["businessType"],
      description: snapshot["description"],
      completeOrders: snapshot["completeOrders"],
      fcm: snapshot["fcm"],
      timeStamp: snapshot["joinTimeStamp"],
      lat: snapshot["lat"],
      lng: snapshot["lng"],
      name: snapshot["name"],
      onlineStatus: snapshot["onlineStatus"],
      picUrl: snapshot["picUrl"],
      rating: snapshot["rating"],
      uuid: snapshot["uuid"],
    );
  }
}
```

**This is a database service class**

```
class DatabaseService {
  final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('kjobhee');

  Stream<List<Seller>> getSellersStream() {
    final sellerStream = _database.child('seller').onValue;
    final streamToPublish = sellerStream.map((event) {
      final sellerMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);
      final sellerList = sellerMap.entries.map((e) {
        return Seller.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(e.value));
      }).toList();
      return sellerList;
    });
    return streamToPublish;
  }
}

 **This is a CardModel Class**


   class CardModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Seller> _sellerList = [];
  final _db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('kjobhee');
  StreamSubscription<Event> _sellerStream;
  static const SELLER_PATH = 'seller';

  List<Seller> get seller => _sellerList;

  CardModel() {
    _listenToSeller();
  }

  void _listenToSeller() {
    _sellerStream = _db.child(SELLER_PATH).onValue.listen((event) {
      final allSellers = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);
      _sellerList = allSellers.values
          .map((sellerAsJson) =>
              Seller.fromRTDB(Map<String, dynamic>.from(sellerAsJson)))
          .toList();
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _sellerStream.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

**And this is a main class**

```
   class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
      ),
      drawer: NavigationDrawer(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider<CardModel>(
              create: (_) => CardModel(),
              child: Consumer<CardModel>(
                builder: (context, model, child) {
                  if (model.seller != null) {
                    return Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ListView(
                        children: [
                          ...model.seller.map(
                            (seller) => GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (c) => AddOrder()));
                              },
                              child: Card(
                                shadowColor: kPrimaryColor,
                                elevation: 10,
                                child: Expanded(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                      horizontal:
                                          getProportionateScreenWidth(20),
                                      vertical:
                                          getProportionateScreenHeight(20),
                                    ),
                                    child: Row(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
                                          child: Column(
                                            children: [
                                              CircleAvatar(
                                                radius: 50,
                                              ),
                                              Text(
                                                '${seller.onlineStatus}',
                                                style: customTextStyle,
                                              ),
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        Flexible(
                                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                            child: Column(
                                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                children: [
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Name: ${seller.name}',
                                                    style: customTextStyle,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Complete Orders: ${seller.completeOrders}',
                                                    style: customTextStyle,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Ratings: ${seller.rating}',
                                                    style: customTextStyle,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    'BusinessType: ${seller.businessType}',
                                                    style: customTextStyle,
                                                  ),
                                                  Text(
                                                    'Description: ${seller.description}',
                                                    style: customTextStyle,
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    width: 300,
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      'Address: ${seller.address}',
                                                      maxLines: 3,
                                                      style: customTextStyle,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ]),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to read the keys?

Comment: in main class print the key and their values in card view all of the real-time database. But my question is how to fetch table keys and their  values one by one in Clickable-Card

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot get key of a table directly but you can get key before push the whole query like.

```
String key = _dbRefe.push().key
```

then you must put this key in the query.

Here is the database reference and pass root table name as (dbTName) then child table name like (tbOrderOfBuyers) into  _dbRef.
if you want to make a auto generate key so you just have to do like _dbRef then push() method dot key, like itemId.

```
 DatabaseReference _dbRef =
    FirebaseDatabase().reference().child(dbTName)
              .child(tbOrderOfBuyers);
    
                   String itemID = _dbRef.push().key;

                            final nextOrder = <String, dynamic>{
                              'itemID': itemID,
                              'itemName': itemName,
                              'itemQuantity': itemQuantity,
                              'itemUnit': itemUnit,
                            };
                            _dbRef
                                .child(uuid)
                                .child(orderId)
                                .child(itemID)
                                .set(nextOrder);
```